# How to get LambdaTest session ID from within Playwright tests?

Tags: playwright, cucumberjs, lambdatest

I have automation tests written in Playwright, I'm using CucumberJS with it and my tests are running on LambdaTest. Inside my code I want to print LambdaTest session ID that is generated for each scenario.
How to do it?
Tried already

`let response = JSON.parse(await page.evaluate(() => {}, 'lambdatest_action: ${JSON.stringify({action: "getSessionDetails"})}'));`

`console.info('Test ID is ${response.data.session_id}');`

and it was working fine for some time but now it doesn't (have no idea why). Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Turned out that instead of `getSessionDetails` I should use `getTestDetails`. This way it works, according to the doc on LambdaTest site: https://www.lambdatest.com/support/docs/playwright-test-execution-setup/#getting-session-details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the below code snippet to fetch the session information.

```js
let response = JSON.parse(await page.evaluate(_ => {}, lambdatest_action: ${JSON.stringify({ action: 'getTestDetails' })}))
console.log(response);
```

[Ref](https://www.lambdatest.com/support/docs/playwright-test-execution-setup/#getting-session-details)